# Hostapd and nl80211

Tags: hostapd, access-point, yocto

I have some troubles with hostapd and nl80211, when I try to launch hostapd, this is what I got :

```
# /etc/init.d/hostapd start
Starting HOSTAP Daemon: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

Is it due to the wifi driver (RTL8812au) or nl80211 driver? I work on a ARM based device, with iMX6 processor, the driver is cross-compiled.

Something strange, iwconfig works :

```
# iwconfig 
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

but when I run `iw list` nothing happens.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Additionnal infos:

- Yocto and custom BSP on the iMX6 board
- kernel version 3.14.28
- Linux distribution poky 1.8.1
- Wifi USB key : Edimax EW-7811USC

Regards,

Pierre-Olivier

Answer (score 0):

According to [Arch-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#nl80211_driver_not_supported_on_some_hardware), you need to use the deprecated `wext` driver, to connect you can type the following command:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/example.conf
```